# How can we track/uniquely identify a specific email sent through Amazon SES using amazon SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am successfully sending an email using Amazon SES by the MIME standard. Now, I want to track what happened to the mails each recipient received. I see that there are two ways to have the callbacks for the emails that were sent out, Feedback notification and Event publishing(Amazon SNS). Please help me in understanding how do I specifically identify the callback for each mail sent from my side. I should receive a callbacks like this,

```
{
   "Type": "Notification",
   "MessageId": "2efb9ee6-6bd5-576d-b80d-d0f5e3f44f23",
   "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:#####:ses_beamstyle_com_hk",
   "Message": {
       "notificationType": "Delivery",
       "mail": {
           "timestamp": "2015-07-05T19:30:40.441Z",
           "source": "<no-reply@bs.com.hk>",
           "messageId": "Ev",
           "destination": [
               "<ooto@simulator.amazonses.com>"
           ]
       },
       "delivery": {
           "timestamp": "2015-07-05T19:30:41.101Z",
           "processingTimeMillis": 660,
           "recipients": [
               "ooto@simulator.amazonses.com"
           ],
           "smtpResponse": "250 2.6.0 Message received",
           "reportingMTA": "a9-140.smtp-out.amazonses.com"
       }
   },
   "Timestamp": "2015-07-05T19:30:41.179Z",
   "SignatureVersion": "1",
   "Signature": "xxxxx",
   "SigningCertURL": "xxxxx",
   "UnsubscribeURL": "xxxxx"
}
```

Which identifier should I use to track the emails that were sent through Amazon SES
and How?